# Pushing data from front end to middle tier

Tags: java, html, jsp

Application accepts firstName  and lastName based on given condition.

1. search only firstName (lastName field is disabled)
2. search only lastName  (firstName field is disabled)
3. search by firstName or lastName (both enabled)
4. search by firstName and lastName (both enabled)

For condition 1 and 2 I can take data in JSP and populate business object, push it to service layer for querying the result, but question is how to take data for condition 3 and 4, when both input fields have data.

What should be the logic?
What should be JSP code?

```html
<body>


    <%
        String FirstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String LastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
    //  int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        UserBo bo = new UserBo();
        bo.setId(id);
    //  bo.setId(new Integer(id).toString());
        bo.setFirstName(FirstName);
        bo.setLastName(LastName);
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        int i = userService.insertUser(bo);


        if (i == 1) {
    %>

    Data Inserted Successfully for First Name: ${param.firstName}
    <br> Last Name: ${param.lastName}
    <br> ID: ${param.id}

    <%
        } else {


        }
    %>

</body>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="../jsp/searchActorData.jsp" id=id >
<br>
<br>
<h3>Search by:  

<select id="menu" name ="nameField"> </h3> 
             <option value="null" selected="selected" >--- Please Select---</option>
            <option> Only FirstName </option>
            <option> Only LastName  </option>
            <option> Or </option>
            <option> And </option>
            </select>

<br><br>
First Name <input id="first" type="text" name="firstName"/>
Last Name <input id="last" type="text" name="lastName"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="reset"/>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var last = document.getElementById('last');

menu.onchange = function(){

     var enableFirst = false, enableLast = false;
    switch(menu.options.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
            enableFirst = false;
            enableLast =  false;
            break;
        case 1:
            enableFirst = true;
            enableLast =  false;
            break;
        case 2:
            enableFirst = false;
            enableLast =  true;
            break;
        case 3:
            enableFirst = true;
            enableLast =  true;
            break;
        case 4:
            enableFirst = true;
            enableLast = true;

        default:
            enableFirst = false;
            enableLast =  false;
            break;

    }
    first.disabled = !enableFirst;
    last.disabled = !enableLast;


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are querying the database for results. But the basic idea is to have a common private method say `getUser` that takes in all search parameters and a where clause. Then build your SQL and prepared statement and execute the search. Create other methods like `getUserByFirstName`, `getUserByLastName`, etc. These methods will genereate a where clause and pass it to the private `getUser` method.

Comment: @tima Db Querying code is present in backend. My question is- in JSP how do you call particular method based on user input?

Comment: You should call the same method in the JSP all the time and pass the first name, last name and the selected option from the menu. Then in your bean, figure out which query method to use based on the selected option and pass the right variables.